# QNAP reboots every 16 hours or so

Tags: reboot, qnap

I have a QNAP TS-412. It has 4x 4TB WD Red drives in RAID10.

The poor thing works pretty hard. Virtually 24/7 it runs at 20-30MB/sec as a backup device from a bunch of office computers and a handful of servers.

In the last 2 weeks, seemingly out of nowhere, it has been rebooting every 16 hours or so. It has been under this sort of workload for about 3 years, with only breaks to upgrade the drive capacity every 18 months or so.

Is there anywhere I can go in the console (or via SSH) to see the reason why it is rebooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find anything in the logs as per Wesley's answer. As a result I have gone on-site and swapped the QNAP chassis for a spare chassis I had and put the old drives into the new chassis.

It seems to have been stable for over 2 days now, whilst still under the same sort of load. I suspect the hardware has failed due to an overheating issue, as it was in a reasonably warm location for a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

Connect to your QNAP with a terminal and look in `/mnt/HDA_ROOT/.logs`. Specifically, `kmsg`. You should see a lot of deep information for your perusal, interpretation, and ultimate edification.

Another option is going to the Web UI >> Select System Administration >> System Logs >> tabs across the top will give you UI access to various files.

As for what to look for, it's usually a crap shoot of what looks bad, and what Google tells you is worse.

Comment: Meow meow meow meow meeoowww meow (translation: There's a lot of stuff in there; anything specific I should look at?)

Comment: Meow meow meow meow meeeooowwww meow meow meow meooowwww (I had a look at the section where the timestamps go backwards, indicating a reboot, but can see nothing of interest. I will keep looking).

Comment: *Mew mew rowww SKREEEE!* (QNAP sucks)

Comment: Meow meow meeoowww hhhuuukkkkkkkkkkkkkk meow siiiigh (Then why do I keep buying them?! Sigh.)

Answer (score 2):

if you enable ssh login then

```
ssh admin@<qnap_ip_addr_here>
password: admin
```

then look at /var/log

```
grep ERR *log
```

look at hal_lib.log and hal_lib.log.bak specifically

look for stuff like this. I don't think my HDD was 60C and am suspicious about whether sometimes HDD temp is read incorrectly. It's possible these are setting thresholds not the actual readings. Not sure.

```
hal_lib.log:Get_Temp_Threshold() called, SYS_ERROR_TEMP=70
hal_lib.log:Get_Temp_Threshold() called, HDD_ERROR_TEMP=60
hal_lib.log:Get_Temp_Threshold() called, CPU_ERROR_TEMP=85
hal_lib.log:Get_Temp_Threshold() called, CPU_ERROR_TEMP=85
```

I'm also curious if other people see this:

```
manaRequest.cgi:Tue Oct 21 16:45:48 2014
PD_Is_Exist: can't retrieve port_id value!
hal_daemon:Tue Oct 21 16:45:59 2014
root_get_fan_speed(978): NOT implement.
se_sys_get_SAS_HBA_info(3606):System Error.
disk_manage.cgi:Tue Oct 21 16:46:03 2014
```

you may want to go inside the QNAP qui (hardware) and disable smart fan speed setting and switch to manual speed (medium always?)

when it says "root_get_fan_speed(979): NOT implement."
I'm suspicious.
Since fan speed seems correct in the gui. ~9k when I choose medium, and  >10k when high speed is chosen

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there was some unexpected failure that caused a reboot, then QNAP was deciding it had to resynchronize the drives. And normal operation is allowed while resynchronizing. But I've had problems with activity during the resync. If you have a "constant load"...and it rebooted every 16 hours, I wonder if it was the interaction of the load with the resync.

I had a similar issue, and couldn't get out of the reboot loop until I stopped my backup jobs and let the resync complete (you can find the resync status on the appropriate place in the gui (in storage manager I think). Also the log tells you when a resync starts. Not sure if it logs when it's done. 
The gui definitely will show while it's going (I think as a task/job at the top of the main page also).

summary: check if it's resync'ing. If so, stop outside activity till the resync completes.

You might also set the smartfan setting to manual high speed, to get best cooling.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if rebuild is busy, and how long it will take in mins, by ssh into the NAS and perform:

```
# cat /etc/mdstat
```

You will see the RAID rebuild including remaining time.